# Creating game in C# Unity3D and it doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my snippets doesn't work in vscode , i use Unity 3.5 and VScode lastest version
and public class not show in gameobject
there is my code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class kontrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float berat, tinggiLoncat;
    public private void OnParticleCollision(GameObject bird) {
    };
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void OnMouseDown() {
        bird.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().gravityScale = berat;
        bird;GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 ( bird;GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, tinggiLoncat);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Please define `doesn't work` .. if you get any errors in the console paste them here ... You have some strange code here in the line `bird;GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 ( bird;GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, tinggiLoncat);` .. are these typos? Should be `bird.` instead of `bird;` Please also note that `c#` != `unityscript` .. the latter is a deprecated JavaScript-ish language previously (some years ago) used in earlier Unity versions

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: And what is a `public private void`? Again: Define `doesn't work` .. [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62990898/edit) your question if you already fixed things please update your question accordingly ... add the error message you get (if any)

Comment: i see it at snippets , than doesn't work mean , the script doesn't add game object to sprites in unity

Answer (score 0):

This isnt working because you have many syntax errors and the script isn't compiling so you cant add it obviously.

```
    public private void OnParticleCollision(GameObject bird) { // Public Private? Choose one!
    }; //no semicolon after methods
        
        bird.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().gravityScale
        bird;GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity //why are you using a semicolon, you did it right in the first place.
```

Answer (score -1):

1. `GetComponent` is expensive. Use it once in `Awake` or `Start`, and save the reference. For example:

```cs
class SomeComponent: MonoBehaviour {
    Rigidbody rb;
    void Awake() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void Update() {
        // do something with rb
    }
}
```

2. You're using semicolons instead of periods.

Comment: btw , i change

public private void OnParticleCollision(GameObject bird) {
    };
to
public GameObject bird

and it doesn't add any game object , how to add game  object?